# Is there a problem installing a floodlight upsidedown?

Tags: lighting

I need to mount a few floodlights in my backyard, but due to the downward angle and how it will be mounted, I must do it upside down. Is there a problem with that?

Some of the other floodlights will be installed facing directly down.

Those are cheap chinese 50W LED floodlights. They have a rubber gasket all around it, and seems to me water resistant at least. I'm more worried about water entering where the cable exit the case.

[image: floodlight upsidedown]

Comment: Unless your backyard is a prison yard, 50W is a LOT of light.

Comment: They are not all in the backyard. 2 are in a 10x2m corridor; 4 in the backyard (13x11m with 2 facing the back and 2 facing down the main area).
I run a few tests with those lights before and one was not enough and 2 was just right for the amount a light I need in each area (corridor, patio, full backyard).

Comment: @Harper if they were a 50w draw I'd agree that a ridiculous amount of LED light.  For some reason tho the lighting industry in the USA is being extremely slow at converting users to lumens as the means to express quantity of light, instead the lighting industry keeps using Watt equivelent numbers to give consumers some idea of how bright the light.

Comment: Actually those are 50w draw, about 4750 lumens +-10%. Since those are cheap Chinese I would guess 4000 to be safe. I'm there using 8 thousand lumens for each area. The corridor is 16 m² and I want it really bright (it is an open corridor) as it is an extension of the  a laundry area and "patio" is about 30m². The backyard lawn is about 100 something m².

Comment: If the only entry point you're concerned about is where the wire enters, make a sleeve out of Sugru or oogroo to seal the wire and clamp.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a problem mounting those Chinese jobs upside down -- *per se*.   For LEDs, orientation is not a big issue; it helps if the heat sink (if any) can have good convection but that can happen in several orientations.

Of course that depends on their build quality, which can vary dramatically amongst brands/makes in that general category.  In that case, shelter makes more of a difference than orientation.   I am rather fond of mounting LED lights of that type inside the diffuser of old 100-175W discharge lights, where you can barely tell they're not a discharge light.